# Как программно сгенерировать клик на ajax элементе

Tags: javascript, ajax, события, click

На странице, как вы поняли, динамически прогружается html. Необходимо произвести клик на один из этих элементов после прогрузки страницы.

Я так и не смог понять, что для этого нужно. Были попытки сделать функцию в таймере и повесить событие в таймере на родительский элемент. Однако, проблема в том что клик должен привести к новому ajax запросу, висячему на этих элементах, а до них я добраться не могу.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
timer = setInterval('Pilot.check()', 60000);
setTimeout(function(){   //начало кода с таймером
    console.log('Задача начата');
    Pilot.check();
}, 6000);                //конец
Pilot = {
check: function(){
    if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pilot")) == null){
        //не по делу код
    }else{
        console.log('База сть, проверка даты');
        var today = new Date().getDate();
        DATA = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pilot"));
        tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
        if(DATA.date < today || (today == 1 && DATA.date != 1)){
            DATA.current = task_type[0];
            DATA.on_work = true;
            DATA.date = today;
            tasks.unshift([task_type[0], 0]);
            DATA.cur_city = 0;
            localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
            localStorage.setItem("pilot", JSON.stringify(DATA));
            console.log('Дата неверная, обновляю');
            **$('li.ownCity')[1].click();** //этот элемент добавляется на страницу динамически
        }else Pilot.start_mission();
    }
},
```

P.S. Попытка #2 реализовать через dispatchEvent также оказалась безуспешной...

Comment: Пример кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: а где вы делаете ajax запрос?

Comment: Ajax запрос возникнет после инициации события click по элементу сайта, поэтому мое участие в его инициации - косвенное, через событие click, которое я пытаюсь выполнить на элементе, загруженном через тот же ajax.